# Using the result of a bash function with bash commands

Tags: shell-script, pipe

I created a bash function called `get`:

```
get() {
    $(fd -H | fzf)
}
```

`fd` is like `find`, and it pipes all files it found into `fzf` a fuzzy finder, which allows me to find a file.

I would like to be able to use `get` with various commands, e.g. `echo` or `ls`, but I can't "get" it to work (excuse the pun), e.g.

```
# I am in home dir, and the result from get is 'Documents'
$ ls $(get)
Documents: command not found

$ ls `get`
Documents: command not found

$ echo get | ls
# Just performs ls on current dir not result from get

$ ls get
ls: cannot access 'get': No such file or directory
```

Not sure how to use the function I made, literal doesnt work, evaluation doesnt work, piping doesnt work, I am out of tricks, so I'm piping the issue into SO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enclosing in `$(` is not what you want: it will try to run a command with the output of that pipeline. Just remove the command substitution and it will work fine:

```
get() {
    fd -H | fzf
}
```

You can then pass to other commands as usual:

```bash
foo "$(get)"
```

Or, if you are relying on word splitting:

```bash
foo $(get)
```

As an aside, since filenames can contain newlines, what you really want is:

```bash
get() {
    fd -0 -H | fzf --read0
}
```

Comment: Wow! Even the ` -0` and `--read0`, masterful!